# 3 Div's 100%, 30% cada, uma na esquerda outra no meio e outra direta

Tags: html, css

Olá estou com um problema nesse CSS básico, tenho uma div pai 100%, preciso que o primeiro filho fique grudado a esquerda o outro no meio e o outro na direita.

Tentei algo com nth-child mas não me serviu muito porque sera um carrousel.

Abraço!

```
<style type="text/css">

.pai {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.filho {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<div class="pai">

    <div class="filho"></div>
    <div class="filho"></div>
    <div class="filho"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comportar 3 elementos de dimensões iguais em um container, tera de usar algo que possa calcular essas dimensões exatas, pois pense comigo, ao dividir 100/3 temos um numero infinito, logo setar o width diretamente não seria a resolução ideal, então pode-se obter esse resultado com a propriedade `flex` das `flexbox`.

```css
.pai {
  display: flex;
}
.filho {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">

    <div class="filho">esquerda</div>
    <div class="filho">centro</div>
    <div class="filho">direita</div>

</div>
```

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Propriedade flex](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)

[Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks, Abraço!

Comment: Não conhecia a propriedade flex, era tudo oque precisava! vlw

Comment: @Josimara, por nada, mas fique atenta ao suporte entre os navegadores, pois os mais antigos não suportam essa propriedade, pode obter informações aqui https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o Flexbox, o que acha?

```css
     body{padding: 0;margin: 0;}
 .pai{display: flex;justify-content: center;}
 .filho{padding: 20px;border: 1px solid; width: 20%; flex-grow: 1;margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="pai">
  <div class="filho">Filho1</div>
  <div class="filho">Filho2</div>
  <div class="filho">Filho3</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Abraço!